# Why replica appears in all 5 nodes, inspite the replication factor is only 3

Tags: cassandra

I am using CCM for training purpose and I have set the keyspace to have RF to 3 and I have 5 nodes. As per the endpoints for the partition key the replicas are to be present in node3, node4 and node5. But I am also able to see the replica in node 1 and node 2. can someone explain why?

Comment: Can you give the CREATE KEYSPACE and CREATE TABLE script of your schema ?

Comment: What do you mean by "see the replica"? How do you check whether node1 and node2 have the data?

Comment: I loged into cqlsh for that corresponding nodes (node 1 and node2) and I could see the data in them when the endpoints clearly say that the replica goes to only node 3, 4 and 5

Comment: That does not mean the data is on any of those particular nodes. Just that the cluster was able to find the rows on some node.

Answer (score 0):

The node you connect to with cqlsh serves as the coordinator. It means that it is able to determine which nodes own the data you want. Whatever node you connect to, it gives you any data you ask, wherever the data is located.

The notion of replica is opaque to you, you cannot easily know where the data is.